# I'm having trouble importing a file in the database/index.js folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, nodemon, adminjs

The problem is on line 2, import './database/index.js'.

Server.js

```
import './database/index.js'
```

And this is the index.js file, which is being imported into server.js.

```
import Sequelize from "sequelize";
import config from '../config/database';
import Model from '../models'
const models = [];
class Database {
    constructor() {
        this.connection = new Sequelize(config);
        this.init() this.associate()
    }
    init() {
        models.forEach((model) => model.init(this.connection))
    }
    associate() {
        models.forEach((model) => {
            if (model.associate) {
                model.associate(this.connection.models);
            }
        })
    }
}
export default new Database();
```

Package.json

```
"type": "module",
```

My console:

```
   [nodemon] starting `node ./src/server.js`
        node:internal/errors:491
            ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
            ^

        Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'D:\Nebula\Templates\Sistema Admin\src\config\database' imported from D:\Nebula\Templates\Sistema Admin\src\database\index.js
            at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:400:5)
            at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:326:11)
            at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:945:10)
            at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1153:11)
            at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
            at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:842:30)
            at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
            at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
            at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
        code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
        }

        Node.js v18.13.0
```

I'm try alterate a type in package.json, but continue error
I believe that the problem is in the way that index.js is being exported, but I don't know another way to do that...
I thought the error was due to not having the .js extension at the end of the import, but I changed it and the same thing continued.

Comment: shouldn't it be `import DB from './database/index.js'`

Comment: cause you need to export a reference

Answer (score 0):

that's the wrong syntax. Try:

```
import * from './database/index.js';
```

or (more DX approach)

```
import { Database } from './database/index.js';
```

Comment: The error continues, I believe it's the way index.js is done, don't you think?